# Оглядывания в регулярных выражениях из стандартной библиотеки

Tags: регулярные-выражения, golang

Я так понял, что оглядывания не поддерживаются. В https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax написано:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

неужели нет альтернатив?

Comment: Нет. Или почти нет, всё зависит от того, что вам конкретно нужно. Вообще никак не получится найти строку, не содержащую какой-то определённый шаблон или подстроку.

Comment: Мне нужно выдрать блок который начинается с шаблона \d\d:\d\d\.\d+ и этим же шаблоном заканчивается. Лан, буду парсить программно

Comment: Обновите вопрос, пожалуйста. Подайте пример + необходимый результат.

Comment: Ключевое слово для поиска — [PCRE](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/PCRE) (гугл вроде знает несколько библиотек для golang)

Comment: Если что, вот пример (с оглядыванием)
https://regex101.com/r/m09xIQ/1

Comment: Читайте файл построчно, проверяйте каждую строку на наличие шаблона `^\d\d:\d\d\.\d+-\d+`, и при совпадении добавляйте строчки во временную переменную, а как только найдётся следующее совпадение, добавьте временную переменную в массив, а переменную обнулите, и продолжайте в том же духе.

Comment: а есть пакет  PCRE в go ?

Comment: "Читайте файл построчно" так и расчитывал

Comment: Вам тут PCRE не нужен (он, конечно, есть). Всё можно реализовать в Go обычными средствами.

Answer (score 1):

Как и написано в документации, оглядывания не поддерживаются. Почему это сделано так описано в [статье](https://swtch.com/~rsc/regexp/regexp1.html) Расса Кокса. Если вкратце, регулярные выражения с оглядыванием имеют в худшем случае сложность O(2<sup>n</sup>), в то время как обычный алгоритм всего O(n<sup>2</sup>).

Для разбора подобных грамматик лучше использовать обычные парсеры.